# Can you make a Single page menu with the standard WP menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to have a single page portfolio website. I am working on a theme I made and I would like to have a single page navigation but I don't know how to do it? Can any one help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use different menu for single page. You can create different header for main page & single page with different menus, and use it in your desired pages using `get_header();`.

For ex:
If you have 2 headers called `header.php` & `header-single.php` then you can use both like `get_header();` & `get_header('single);`